# Having a method automatically run when window loads

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have began to try and learn visual basic.net. I have had previous experience programming in c++ however some of the .net and windows based procedures really confuse me and this is one of them.

I am trying to get a method to load when the main window is initialized. I have been able to get the function to run when put into a click-event however, not when the main window is opened. Here is the code that I am trying to run:

```
    Private Sub Window_Loaded_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    'mPerson = New Person
    myPerson = New Person()
    myPerson = New Person()
    myPerson = New Person()
    ' AddHandler Person.NewPerson, AddressOf OnNewPerson
    MessageBox.Show(myPerson.PersonCount)

    If My.Settings.NoPopup Then
        AddHandler myPerson.Walked, AddressOf LogOnWalk
    Else
        AddHandler myPerson.Walked, AddressOf OnWalk
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated. Please remember I am just learning.

Comment: If you know C++ I highly recommend you try to learn C# first before you try VB.NET, C#'s syntax will be much more familiar to you. Also, for future questions use the tag [tag:vb.net] not [tag:basic], basic is a "ancestor" of VB.NET.

Comment: that is not the proper signature for the load event.  there should be a HANDLES clause.  Dont create them yourself, VS will create the skeleton handler either from the properties pane or using the drop down at the top of the code window (in the form)

Answer (score 0):

If this function is not called elsewhere, you may wish to add an event handler onto it, so that it does as you like. For example,

```
Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender as Object, e as RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Load
```

Which should fire off as soon as the base form is created, provided that you put said code within that form itself, as "Me" in that case will refer to the form itself.

Really, its no different than firing it off of a click-based event, you simply need to find the proper handler. Likewise, if this function is called or used elsewhere, simply have that other function provide the required handler, and then from there call this function.